# python write items prior to first match

Tags: python, list, csv, indexing

i am looking to fine tune this script i wrote.

i remove all items in list1 contained in list0.

however i ran into an issue, and i would like to find the first item in list1 that matches list0 and make a list2 that contains the items in list0 prior to that initial match.

Example:

```
list0 = ['#A', '77', 'TEST', 'ST']
list1 = ['77', 'MAIN', 'ST']

list2 = ['#A']
```

for the example above, my code writes:

```
list2 = ['#A', 'TEST']
```

can anyone help? -thank you

```
import csv

address1_new = csv.writer(open('C:/Users/USR01/python/test1_new.csv', 'ab'))

with open('C:/Users/USR01/python/test1.csv', 'rb') as c:
    reader = csv.reader(c)

    for row in reader:

        address0 = [] #newline for file: *test1_new.csv*

        list0 = row[0].strip().split(' ')
        address0.append(row[0].strip())

        list1 = row[1].strip().split(' ')
        address0.append(row[1].strip())

        list2 = [x for x in list0 if x not in list1]
        address0.append(' '.join(list2))

        #address1_new.writerow(address0)

        print address0
```

Answer (score 0):

Use set():

```
list0 = ['#A', '77', 'TEST', 'ST']
list1 = ['77', 'MAIN', 'ST']
list2 = list(set(list0) - set(list1))
```

https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html

Comment: that returns: `['TEST', '#A']` which is what i am trying to avoid.. i want to get all items prior to the first match. first match is `'77'` so give me `['#A']` from `list0`

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out:

```
item1 = list1[0]

if item1 in list0:
    idx = list0.index(item1)
    print list0[0:idx]
```

Thanks